# User Field value is not assigned?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a trigger.. contact is lookup. and i am assigning contact obj user value to current object.debug logs showing the value existed. but it is not assigned in record field.?

```
trigger NIGO_update on NIGOs__c(before insert,before update){

     List<NIGOs__c> NgList = [select id,name,Contact_Name__c,Product_Type__c,Contact_Name__r.Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__r.id,Contact_Name__r.Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__c,Contact_Name__r.Forecare_Territory_Wholesaler__r.id from NIGOs__c  where id in:Trigger.new];


     for(NIGOs__c ng:NgList){
        if(ng.Product_Type__c != 'Forecare'){
            if(ng.Contact_Name__c != Null){

                **ng.External_Wholesaler__c** = ng.Contact_Name__r.Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__r.id;

            }
        }
        **System.debug('Ext1'+ng.External_Wholesaler__c);**
    }

}
```

Comment: Try debugging the fields where your conditions exist to make sure they match and/or are not null. Also before insert will not have an Id yet so you will not return the related records.

Comment: check that Contact_Name__r. Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__c != null

Comment: yes , i have verified with valid policy record.  and the value is shown in debug logs also

Comment: System debug is outside of all `if` conditions. Please put debug inside conditions and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two things wrong:

**Querying records that do not exist yet in the before insert**

The query will never return any records when its a before insert because the `NIGOs__c` records have not yet been persisted to the database.

**Updating the wrong record instances**

When using before triggers you can update the records from `Trigger.new` without the need to do an update. This is not what you are doing. You are doing a SOQL query to get the `NgList` list and then updating those instances rather than the ones from `Trigger.new`. You could do something like the following to get the correct record to update

```
NIGOs__c nigoFromTrigger = Trigger.newMap.get(ng.Id);
nigoFromTrigger.External_Wholesaler__c = ...
```

but keep in mind that `Id` values are not populated in before insert triggers.

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting error like  'Trigger' variable is not existed  from the line  Trigger.newMap.get(ng.id)...I had taken list instead of Trigger.new  because  from the __r.id  getting null value. So soql the querry to get the value

Comment: I have updated the code snippet in my answer